# How to Use EJB 3.1 Automatic Non-Persistent Timer in Clustered Environment on Websphere?

Tags: java, timer, ejb-3.1, websphere-8

Regarding Automatic(using **@Schedule**) Persistent and Non-Persistent timers in a Clustered Environment, the documentation states that a persistent timer runs in only one cluster member, and an automatic non-persistent timer runs in each cluster member that contains the EJB:

From [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tejb_timerserviceejb_enh.html):

> **Timers in a clustered environment**
>
> In a clustered environment, a persistent timer runs only in one
>   cluster member which might not necessarily be the same cluster member
>   it was created in. A non-persistent timer runs in each cluster member
>   that it was created in - automatic non-persistent timers run in each
>   cluster member that contains the EJB.

I would like to use this feature of a Persistent timer (only run the timer on one cluster member), but I don't want the "persistent" feature, which specifies that the timer will survive a server restart or crash and try to "catch up" timer events that were unable to fire.

Is there a way to have an automatic non-persistent timer that runs on only one cluster member? Or, is it possible to turn off the "catch up" feature of the Persistent timer?

Answer (score 0):

The capability that you are asking for (a non-persistent timer that only runs on one cluster member and without "catch up" of previously missed expirations) is not built in to WebSphere Application Server.  There are, however, a couple of ways that you can simulate it.

First option: Schedule a persistent EJB interval timer that invokes javax.ejb.Timer.getTimeRemaining and skips itself when negative.

Second option: schedule a non-persistent timer on each member. Use a database or other persistent store to record the timestamp of the most recently attempted execution.  When the non-persistent timers attempt to run, attempt an update of the persistent store to replace the timestamp with current timestamp if it hasn't run recently.  If successful, then run the timer, otherwise don't.  This could work well if there are relatively few cluster members, otherwise there might be too much contention on the database.

Comment: I don't think the getTimeRemaining suggestion is reliable.  As I recall, it will always return 0 from within the timeout callback method.  Perhaps I remember incorrectly and it returns (time-now), but in that case, it will often be negative (at least intermittently) once the overhead of invoking the method is considered.

Comment: Before posting the answer, I did try out Timer.getTimeRemaining from within the timeout callback, where several executions had been missed. My timer--which was scheduled to run every 2 seconds--reported Timer.getTimeRemaining values of (-15860, -13943, -11966, -9990, -8013, -6033, -4055, -2075, -97, 1883, 1984, ...). It switched from negative to positive when there started to be a delay between executions again, having fully caught up on the missed executions. I'll add that I only tried this on WebSphere Application Server Liberty, not traditional.  It's possible the behavior might not match.

Comment: Ah, perhaps clarify in your answer that you meant an interval timer rather than a single-action timer, which has different behavior for getTimeRemaining.  (Regardless, if the interval is sufficiently small and/or the system is sufficiently loaded, I think there is still a risk for a "false positive" of a negative getTimeRemaining even for a non-catchup invocation, so I'm not sure this is a robust suggestion.)

Comment: Thanks, I have added the clarification about interval timers, just in case I had misinterpreted the question.  Regarding the point about false positives, I don't really agree here. The person who asked the question will ultimately decide, but I believe the intent is to skip the catch-up behavior. Whether it is due to the server being down or an overly loaded system shouldn't matter. If getTimeRemaining has a negative value, then as soon as the current execution finishes, the next will begin, which is what they are trying to avoid.  Response continued...

Comment: If anything, I'd question if they might want to go further in the opposite direction and compare against a positive value that is some portion of the repeating interval.  For example, if the goal is to launch a job hourly which could take up to 30 minutes to run, then maybe they would want to skip launching the job if there were less than 30 minutes remaining and so they would compare with a value of 1800000ms.